# How do I get a CSS button to render another HAML page in a new window?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Basically, I have a HAML file with a button that is generated by calling a CSS class.  I want this button to render another HAML page in a new window.  I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: What did you find when you searched the internet? What have you tried?

Comment: `a` with blank target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, just make it a link with `target=blank`

haml using rails' link_to helper:

```
= link_to "Click Me", some_new_page_path, class: 'btn', target: "_blank"
```

haml without rails helper:

```
%a.btn{href: '/path/to/page', target: "_blank"} Click Me
```

generated HTML:

```
<a href='/path/to/page' class='btn' target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```